# Set annotation X1 and X2 on BoxAnnotationViewModel to be between major grid units on CategoryDateTimeAxis

Tags: c#, wpf, annotations, scichart

I am using scicharts BoxAnnotationViewModel to highlight a particular selection of price data from a FastCandleStickRenderableSeries. Currently setting the BoxAnnotaions X1/X2 has undesirable results as it will place this in the middle of the desired candle as the X1/X2 input only accepts an integer index  for a CategoryDateTimeAxis. I would like to be able to offset this X1/X2 input by 0.5 units to encompass the entire candle/candle range desired.

Is this a possibility that I have missed in the SciChart docs using the default built in BoxAnnotationViewModel on a CategoryDateTimeAxis for financial data?

Thank you,

Using SciChart Version: WPF 6.1.1.13136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's new way to specify a half data-point for [BoxAnnotation](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/The%20BoxAnnotation%20Type.html) on [CategoryDateTimeAxis](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Axis%20Types%20in%20SciChart.html) in [SciChart WPF Charts](https://www.scichart.com/wpf-chart-features). The axis type expects integer data-points.

For SciChart iOS, Android this limitation has been overcome and CategoryDateTimeAxis accepts floating-point indices for smoother scrolling.

You can if you want, request a feature for 'Floating point indexes on CategoryDateTimeAxis' over at the [scichart feedback portal](https://www.scichart.com/feedback-policy).

Comment: Thank you for the info, I was afraid that was the case but I will put in that feedback. Is this possible in WPF on a categorDateTimeAxis at all with a custom annotation? Or is that functionality just not present?

Comment: Not present at all. The axis requires an integral (whole number) coordinate for the index to data.